# Restart Python with threading or crontab

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have written a function that crawls and clusters news articles. I want this function to restart every 10 minutes, aiming to get the newest articles. I wrote a Python script that this with the help of threading module:

```
import threading
def run():
    do_it()
    if not END:
        threading.Timer(600.0, run).start()
END = False
threading.Timer(600.0, do_it).start()
```

It works fine with Python IDLE. Now I see in different forums that "crontab" is mentioned for this purpose. Since I plan to host this application on the web and since I have no prior experience with web development/hosting, what would you suggest to me: to continue with the previous code or to try to do it with the "crontab" function? I am working with the Django framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Django doesn't really work in this context.  if you want to use a cron script then you will want it running independently of your webserver (you don't want your webserver ending after you finish the script).  Alternatively you could start up a GET or POST request to an already running Django instance by this method.

First type `crontab -e` at a prompt in your unix based os or mac.  (since you mentioned crontab I'll assume your not using windows)

This will allow you to edit a file for the user you are logged in as.  This is the line you will want to type to get a do_it.py file to run every ten min.

```
*/10 * * * * do_it.py
```

For more information at your prompt type `man 5 crontab`.  Other modifications you could make are prefixing the word `sudo` to the command which would allow you to change root's crontab.

Comment: I am using windows actually. I mentioned crontab because I'm planning to host the application and I saw that people are mentioning it. That is my question about: if I host the application on for example Pythonware or webfaction, should I continue with the "threading" module or it is better to see how "crontab" functions and implement it? With the do_it function I am crawling and clustering news artciles, and put the results on files. Then I use Django to produce web pages from these results (they are read from the files)

Comment: It depends, are you ssh'ing into a windows box or a linux box on webfaction?  Debugging multiple threads is ... a nuisance.  Write single threads until you have to get more speed.  Cron is a great timer for linux.  And if you are running this on windows then ask your webhost to switch you to linux and see option #1. j/k take a look at the "at" command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx or "schtasks" (you aren't supposed to pronounce it) http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx

Comment: I haven't decided about the web host yet. But I think you gave me a lot of information on this matter. Thank you @Back2Basics